# I need help to make my character to be able to change postion smoothly using keyboard controls

Tags: javascript

Every time I press one of these keys, it just moves further and further.

```js
function update() {
  window.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
      switch (e.key) {
        case 'w':
          myY = myY + 1;
          break
        case 'a':
          myX = myX - 1;
          break
        case 's':
          myY = myY - 1;
          break
        case 'd':
          myX = myX + 1;
          break
      }
    }
  })
```

Comment: What do you mean by smoothly? Please include the code that calls `update` as well

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve a smooth movement, you need:

- a tick loop
- listening both on *keydown* and *keyup* events

Given the presence of the `update()` function, I think you already have a tick loop.

Note that the `addEventListener()` should only be called during the setup phase.
Here's an example:

```
let speedX = 0
let speedY = 0

function setup() {  
  window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
      switch (e.key) {
        case 'w':
          speedY += 1;
          break
        case 'a':
          speedX -= 1;
          break
        case 's':
          speedY -= 1;
          break
        case 'd':
          speedX += 1;
          break
      }
  }

  window.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
      switch (e.key) {
        case 'w':
          speedY -= 1;
          break
        case 'a':
          speedX += 1;
          break
        case 's':
          speedY += 1;
          break
        case 'd':
          speedX -= 1;
          break
      }
   }
}

function update() {
  myX += speedX;
  myY += speedY;
}
```

---

If you do not have a tick loop, here's one way to make one with `requestAnimationFrame`:

```
function loop() {
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  update();
}

setup();
loop();
```